# How to compute maximum modulus on unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + \cdots + a_{n-1}z^{n-1}$ and $|a_i|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ for all $i$.

I want to know maximum modulus 
$|p(z)|$ on $|z|=1$.

By the maximum modulus theorem and triangle inequality, $|p(z)| < \frac{n^2}{2}$.

But it's very trivial upper bound.
How to compute a maximum modulus or nice upper bound??

Comment: How did you come up with $|p(z)| < \frac{n^2}{2}$? Unless I am mistaken, the triangle inequality gives $|p(z)| \le \frac{n}{2}$, and that is best possible (take all $a_i= \frac 12$ and $z= 1$).

Comment: Oh sorry n/2 right

Comment: But then you have the best possible bound. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you are asking for, say, how to apply the maximum modulus principle for the *contour integration* of your $p(z)$ on the contour that is the unit circle (or anything else), then the upper bound on the modulus of your integral is **ML**, where $M$ is the maximum of $p(z)$ on the contour, and $L$ is the length of the contour, which, for a unit circle, is just the circumference, $2\pi $.

This ML-bound comes up a lot in complex integration problems.